# Lampp MySql no pid no tc,log ERROR 2002 (HY000) All together unbreakable

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, lampp

This is my crying status, Apache is running but My dear, Mysql is not...

```
2017-01-10 17:42:28 22497 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/spasibo.pid ended
2017-01-10 18:20:45 25932 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.8-MariaDB) starting as process 26072 ...
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1600936 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2017-01-10 18:20:46 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2017-01-10 18:20:47 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-01-10 18:20:47 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-01-10 18:20:47 3072497408 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1600936
2017-01-10 18:20:47 2855246656 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-01-10 18:20:47 3072497408 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-01-10 18:20:47 3072497408 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2017-01-10 18:20:47 3072497408 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2017-01-10 18:20:47 3072497408 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2017-01-10 18:20:47 3072497408 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2017-01-10 18:20:47 3072497408 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2017-01-10 18:20:47 3072497408 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-01-10 18:20:47 3072497408 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2017-01-10 18:20:47 25932 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/spasibo.pid ended
```

I have made a research about this trouble but nothing seems to solve it

Please! Where Is the Hero that can solve this!